# Using JS to write CSS will cancel :hover properties defined in stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, inline-styles

I have two divs. One is parent of the other. When I hover over the parent the child gets a different background color and font color. However when I run the function switch() that changes the inline style of the child element the hover propertie is canceled. In other words: after applying CSS with JS the child background doesn't change on hover.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.foo').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
}
.foo {
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container:hover > .foo {
  background-color: #c01919;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="foo">Hey there!</div>
</div>

<button>.foo(backgroundColor) -> green</button>
```

The real question is how to prevent inline style from canceling CSS :hover properties?

Is there a way to make the background color red on hover **after** the function has affected the inline style?

Comment: where is the JSFiddle link?

Comment: Well I just copied it to the post

Comment: I think that no, as inline style property has highest privilige in style inheritance.

Comment: you have the code in the post!

Comment: @NiharSarkar — The OP included a live demo in the question itself. What would be the point in duplicating it on a third party site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The real question is how to prevent inline style from canceling CSS :hover properties?

Short of using `!important` (which is awful, so don't), you can't. The point of inline style is that it is more specific that any selector.

Stop using inline style. Set the green colour in the stylesheet and then activate it by using JavaScript to change the classes that the element is a member of.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.foo').classList.add('bar');
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
}
.foo {
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.bar {
  background-color: green; 
}
.container:hover > .foo {
  background-color: #c01919;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="foo">Hey there!</div>
</div>

<button>.foo(backgroundColor) -> green</button>
```

Comment: So I shouldn't use: `.....style.color = 'red'` and other JS methods of this kind ?

Comment: @Ivan — In general they are more trouble than they are worth, in this particular case they don't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Inline style has a higher privilege than styles defined in a stylesheet or in `<style>` tags unless `!important` is used in the definition of the rule. Your use case looks like instead of making the button green with inline style, adding a class (maybe `is-clicked`) would better. Then you would prevent ugly inline style, have a semantic class naming and no problems overwriting that style with css.

```
document.querySelector('.foo').classList.add('is-clicked');
```

Note: classList is not supported in (very) old browsers. Depending on the target audience I would say it is OK to use: http://caniuse.com/#search=classlist

Comment: There is no `addClass` method an HTML element object.

Comment: Damn right! should be 

   document.querySelector('.foo').classList.add('is-clicked');

for the vast majorities of currently used browsers.

Comment: @Quentin - I noticed that just after I posted my comment, which is why I tried to delete it quickly. Sorry about that.